# Entangled Photon Sources: how to choose the pump wavelength in SPDC?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, laser, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

I found several papers dealing with entangled pairs of photons generated by means of a setup consisting in a pump laser and a nonlinear crystal, such as BBO or KTP and here the incoming photons experience Spontaneous Parametric Down Conversion (SPDC). Often the central wavelength of the pump is around 405 nm. What are the criteria behind these choices? Are there any restrictions in the choice of source or crystal?

Thanks

Comment: Read here, pagg. 9-11: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1809/1809.00127.pdf